# set beamer frame attributes without frame title

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, beamer

I am writing `rmd` code to be exported to a beamer presentation. It turns out that for LaTeX reasons I need to make the beamer frame `fragile`. I read [in the R Markdown documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex#frame_attributes_in_beamer) that frame attributes can be set by adding, for instance, `{.fragile}` to a section title. Yet I do not want a title for the frame in question.

In the following sample code the `fragile` attribute is passed successfully to the first frame. Trying to do the same with `---` does not result in a second frame.

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

## title {.fragile}

text

---

more text
```

How can I get a second frame, one that is `fragile` and has no title?

Comment: Can you try with an empty frametitle, e.g. `# {.fragile}`? Most default themes will print the frametitle only if it is non-empty, so an empty title should not hurt

Comment: Can you please show the resulting .tex code which needs a fragile frame? Maybe there is some workaround to use it without fragile

Answer (score 1):

Luckily most beamer themes are smart enough to show the frametitle only if it is non-empty - this means you can trick markdown with a frametitle that just contains `{.fragile}`

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
---

# title {.fragile}

text

---

# {.fragile}

more text
```

which results in the tex code

```
\begin{frame}[fragile,fragile]{title}
\protect\hypertarget{title}{}

text

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,fragile]{}
\protect\hypertarget{section}{}

more text

\end{frame}
```

(I have no idea why the `fragile` option appears twice ...)